# Tkinter - way to find out the last row used?

Tags: python, tkinter

This code is looping through RSS feeds to get news summaries. The summaries are varying in length and changing.

As I'm populating these with a simple offset each loop `row = i + 5`, the `wraplength` option sometimes causes the previous line to go more 5 lines, causing the offset to fail in writing the next story below the previous one.

Is there a way that I could reference the most recently used row and just have the next story populate below that?

```
section_start = 9 
news_root = Frame(root, bg = 'green').grid(row = section_start, column = 0, columnspan = 4, rowspan = 20, sticky = W)

url = 'http://feeds.nytimes.com/nyt/rss/Business'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, features = 'xml')

items = soup.findAll('item')

for item in items[:5]: 
   i += 2
   news_title = Label(news_root, text = item.title.text, fg = 'mediumblue', bg = 'white', font = ('Calibri',10))
   new_title.grid(row = i, column = 0, columnspan = 4, rowspan =4, sticky = 'W')

   news_des = Label(news_root, text = item.description.text, fg = 'dimgray', bg = 'white', font = ('Calibri',8), wraplength = 500,  justify = LEFT)
   news_des.grid(row = i+5, column = 0, rowspan =4, columnspan = 10, sticky = W)
```

Comment: Is there any way you could simplify your question and maybe provide a code snippet has better focus on what you're asking?

Comment: Can you use a text widget instead of a label to display the results?

Comment: Yeah sorry - noticing my code spirals out of control with Tkinter, so hard to follow. Basically, my question boils down to - if I were to split a root window into two frames down the middle horizontally to create a top and bottom, and I'm populating the top through a loop (which varies in length based off the text feeding in - it could be 10 lines, it could be 20) - is there a way to tell the second frame (bottom) where it should begin?

Comment: @user6142489: there's no need. Use `pack` to put the top frame on top, and the bottom frame on the bottom. It doesn't matter how many rows are inside the top frame.